# Excel Pivot Table: Show aggregated data in one column and the actual data in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have an excel document and inside this document, there are two sheets: 1. Actual Project Hours 2. Planned Project Hours. The actual project hours is broken down into projects, resources, hours taken on the project etc... The snapshot of this data is provided here for reference:
[image]

On the other hand, I have a monthly breakdown of each project like this:

[image]

So I am trying to come up with a pivot table where I am able to aggregate the project and months based on the Actual Project Hours sheet but now I want to do a side-by-side comparison with the planned project hours that requires no aggregation but just showing the values:
[image]

How do I accomplish this in excel using the existing pivot table that I have built?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to your first table which looks up the monthly total from the second table. Then you use that new column in your pivot table with the Average aggregation (since there are multiple rows per month).

Both formulas do the same thing, so choose whichever you prefer.

The formula in the "Planned" column:

```
=XLOOKUP([@[Project Name]],planned[Project Name],XLOOKUP([@[Month Starting]],planned[[#Headers],[Jan]:[Feb]],planned[[Jan]:[Feb]]))
```

The formula in the "Planned2" column:

```
=INDEX(planned[[Jan]:[Feb]],XMATCH([@[Project Name]],planned[Project Name]),XMATCH([@[Month Starting]],planned[[#Headers],[Jan]:[Feb]]))
```

[image]